# Windows phone 8.1 custom keyboard

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, ios-keyboard-extension

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard that I can add to the Windows phone similar to how the IPhone allows for different system keyboard types (Emojo icon keyboard, symbol keyboards etc..). Is there a way to do this in Windows phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry. Custom keyboards are not supported on Windows Phone.

You can vote on the feature request at the [Windows Platform Dev Feedback site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/2976742-custom-keyboard-via-code)

Comment: Lol.. Well they should be!